# Velocity of the touching point between 2 rotating circles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I'm trying to solve the following problem that I'm having a hard time with:

We have circle ${\Sigma}_1$ with center $O_1$ and radius $a_1$. The center $O_1$ is also the center of the static orthonormal coordinate system $R_0 (O_1, x_0, y_0, z_0)$. ${\Sigma}_1$ rotates at the angular speed ${\omega}_1$.

Be the circle ${\Sigma}_2$ with center $O_2$ and radius $a_2<a_1$ rolling without slipping on top of ${\Sigma}_1$  at a constant angular speed ${\omega}_2$. We call **I** the touching point between the two circles.

Be ${\Sigma}_3$ a solid keeping ${\Sigma}_1$ and ${\Sigma}_2$  in contact.

The coordinate system $R_0$ defined by $(O_1, _0, _0, _0)$ is fixed and does not rotate.

The coordinate system $R$ defined by $(O_1,  ,  ,  )$ is mobile and fixed to ${\Sigma}_3$  and rotates around $z≡z_0$ at the angular speed ${\omega}_3$.

[image: Schematics of the 2 circle system]

I need to find the velocity of **I** in the $R_0$ coordinate basis when $\omega_1=0$ and then find $\omega_3$ as a function of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.

I know how to express the velocity of **I** when $\omega_2=0$ which I solved, but after trying for more than $2$ hours with different methods like changing coordinates systems and creating a third one centered at $O_2$, I could not find a satisfactory answer.
Does any of you have an answer?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't the velocity of **I** zero when $\omega_2 = 0$ ?

Comment: Not necessarily, if $_1$ is non null, its velocity is dependent to $_1$ , which I know how to calculate. Problem is when $_1$ is null but $_2$ isn't. I can't seem to find a change in the reference system that would get me the velocity as a function of $_2$.

Comment: I know this is off topic but how did you calculate it. To me, since $\Sigma_2$ rolls without slipping, $\omega_2 = 0$ means $\omega_1 = 0$

Comment: Hi there! Do you need to know the (instantaneous) linear velocities? What did you find for the velocity of **I** when ${\omega}_2=0$ (and ${\omega}_1 \neq 0$, I suppose)?

Comment: I guess I wasn't very clear on my description of the problem. ${\Sigma}_2$ rolls on ${\Sigma}_1$ when $_2$ is not zero. When $_2$ is zero, then it follows ${\Sigma}_1$ on its rotation as it is attached to it by ${\Sigma}_3$, therefore **I** only depends on $_1$ and we find its velocity with the derivative of the position vector $O_1$I.

Comment: Hi descheleschilder. Yes I need to find its linear velocities in $R_0$. 
For $_2$=0 and $_1$ non null, I find that **I** velocity is determined by the derivative of the position vector $O_1$I. Which gives: -$a_1$$_1$sin($_1$t) for $x_0$  and $a_1$$_1$cos($_1$t) for $y_0$.

(Sorry for the formatting, I'm new here)

Comment: **I need to find the velocity of I in the $R_0$ coordinate basis when $\omega_1=0.$** Is ${\omega}_3 \neq 0$ in this case?

Comment: Yes, $_3$ is non null in that case because $_2$ in non null either.

Comment: So, in this case, the angular velocity of **I** is ${\omega}_3$?

Comment: It is, but I need to find it's velocity as a function of $_2$ and then determine the relationship between $_1$, $_2$ and $_3$.
I thought about using $_3$ in my expressions, but even tho it's not specified, it's not what's expected by the question.

Comment: If the system $R$ has made one full rotation, then how much rotations did ${\Sigma}_2$ make? In other words, how many times ${\omega}_2$ is ${\omega}_3$ (using $a_1$ and $a_2$)?

Comment: **I need to find the velocity of I in the $R_0$ coordinate basis when $\omega_1=0$ and then find $\omega_3$ as a function of $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$.** Doesn't this mean you have to find angular velocities instead of linear velocities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ${\omega}_1=0$, ${\omega}_2=(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+1){\omega}_3$ (the factor $1$ appears because ${\Sigma}_2$ makes one extra turn after having rolled one turn around ${\Sigma}_1$ in the $R_0$ coordinate base).
So ${\omega}_3=\frac{{\omega}_2}{(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+1)}$. When ${\omega}_1\neq0$, we have to add this to ${\omega}_3$, so: ${\omega}_3=\frac{{\omega}_2}{(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+1)}+{\omega}_1$.

You can use this expression for ${\omega}_3$ to find the linear velocities (involving the $\sin$ and $\cos$ functions).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The velocity at the contact point I is:

$$v_I=\omega_1\,a_1-\omega_2\,a_2$$

thus the components of the velocity in $R_0$ coordinate system are:

$$\vec{v}_0=v_I\,\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\varphi)\\
   \sin(\varphi)
\end{bmatrix}$$

with  $\varphi=\int\,\omega_3(t)\,dt=\omega_3\,t\quad $ if $\quad\omega_3=$constant